# Pandas: Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a file.txt using pandas like this :

```
option19971675181       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1                                 blabla    88   498
option19971675182       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA  1                                  blabla   176   498
option19971675183       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1                                  blabla   191   498
option19971675184       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1                                  blabla   521   498
option19971675185       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1                                  blabla   919   498
option19971675186       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA134234531                          blabla    10    498
option19971675187       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA134234531 7 65                     blabla     0     0
option19971675188       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1342 90345 31                      blabla     0     0
option19971675189      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87OP531                blabla     0     0
option19971675190       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87  OP53                blabla     0     0
```

The columns values are separated by multiples spaces so i writed the code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", delimiter ="\s\s+", header = None)
```

The problem here that i got some extra spaces in the **text(ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA   1 )** for exp :

```
option19971675190       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87  OP53                blabla     0     0
option19971675182       ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA  1                                  blabla   176   498
```

This Extra spaces cause and error : `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 5 fields in line, saw 6. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.`

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can work around this by setting our seperator to "3 or more spaces":

```
df = pd.read_csv(text, sep="\s{3,}", header=None)
print(df)
```

```
                   0                                         1       2    3    4
0  option19971675181                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla   88  498
1  option19971675182                    ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA  1  blabla  176  498
2  option19971675183                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla  191  498
3  option19971675184                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla  521  498
4  option19971675185                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla  919  498
5  option19971675186              ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA134234531  blabla   10  498
6  option19971675187         ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA134234531 7 65  blabla    0    0
7  option19971675188          ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1342 90345 31  blabla    0    0
8  option19971675189   ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87OP531  blabla    0    0
9  option19971675190  ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87  OP53  blabla    0    0
```

**Note:** although this solution works, your file format looks more like a fixed width format and thus you should use [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

```
df = pd.read_fwf(text, colspecs="infer", header=None)
print(df)
```

```
                   0                                         1       2          3
0  option19971675181                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla   88   498
1  option19971675182                    ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA  1  blabla  176   498
2  option19971675183                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla  191   498
3  option19971675184                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla  521   498
4  option19971675185                      ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1  blabla  919   498
5  option19971675186              ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA134234531  blabla  10    498
6  option19971675187         ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA134234531 7 65  blabla    0     0
7  option19971675188          ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA1342 90345 31  blabla    0     0
8  option19971675189   ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87OP531  blabla    0     0
9  option19971675190  ACHILLE BLA BLA BLA 134 23N 094 87  OP53  blabla    0     0
```